# Merge two objects in php with slightly different properties

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object, merge

I have two object arrays which are populated from a DB query and defined like so:

**array1:**

```
foreach ($grade_records as $record) {
    $grade_object = new stdClass();
    $grade_object->fields = array(
        'id'    => $record->id,
        'grade'    => $record->grade,
        'user_id'   => $record->user_id,
        'course_id' => $record->course_id,
    );

    array_push($grades, $grade_object);
}
```

**array2:**

```
foreach ($attendance_records as $record) {
    $attendance_object = new stdClass();
    $attendance_object->fields = array(
        'id'         => $record->id,
        'attendance' => $record->attendance,
        'user_id'    => $record->user_id,
        'course_id'  => $record->course_id
    );

    array_push($attendance, $attendance_object);
}
```

I want to merge these arrays to an array containing objects that have the combined properties of each object, in the most efficient way.
i tried using the following code:

```
foreach ($attendance as $att_record) {
    foreach ($grades as $grd_record) {
        if ($att_record->id == $grd_record->id) {
           $new = (object) array_merge((array) $att_record, (array) $grd_record);
           array_push($final_array, $new);
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives me an array without the added "grade" property. 
I also tried using `array_merge_recursive` but it changes nothing.

**EDIT:**
Ended up using this:

```
foreach ($att_objs as $att_key => $att_data) {
    foreach ($grd_objs as $grd_key => $grd_data) {
        if ($grd_data->fields['Id'] == $att_data->fields['Id']) {
            $merged_obj = new stdclass();
            $merged_obj->fields = array_merge($att_data->fields, $grd_data->fields);
            unset($att_objs[$att_key]);
            unset($grd_objs[$grd_key]);
            array_push($merged_objs, $merged_obj);
        }
    }
}
$merged_objs = array_merge($merged_objs, $att_objs);
$merged_objs = array_merge($merged_objs, $grd_objs);
```

Comment: Any error while executing?

Comment: I don't see any errors while executing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
<?php

$grades = [];

foreach ($grade_records as $record) {
    $grade_object = new stdClass();
    $grade_object->fields = array(
        'id'        => $record->id,
        'grade'     => $record->grade,
        'user_id'   => $record->user_id,
        'course_id' => $record->course_id,
    );

    $grades[$record->id] = $grade_object;
}

$attendance = [];

foreach ($attendance_records as $record) {
    $attendance_object = new stdClass();
    $attendance_object->fields = array(
        'id'         => $record->id,
        'attendance' => $record->attendance,
        'user_id'    => $record->user_id,
        'course_id'  => $record->course_id
    );

    $attendance[$record->id] = $attendance_object;
}

$identifiers = array_intersect(
    array_keys($grades),
    array_keys($attendance)
);

$final_array = [];

foreach ($identifiers as $id) {
    $object = new \stdClass();
    $object->fields = \array_merge(
        $grades[$id]->fields,
        $attendance[$id]->fields
    );

    $final_array[] = $object;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `array_merge()`,if two or more array elements have the same key, the last one overrides the others. In your case, both `$att_record` and `$grd_record` has same keys `'fields'`. So if you replace `'fields'` keys in anyone of them, you will get the desired result.